# Images on google chrome not loading

Tags: java, google-chrome, jakarta-ee

I am new to java, I fetched images data from path and stored in byte array.
While loading images on Google Chrome it gives exception:

> ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Here is my code:

```
byte[] data = getImageData(path,imageName);

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment,fileName=\"" + data);
response.setContentLength(data.length);
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
responseOutputStream.write(data, 0, data == null ? 0: data.length);
responseOutputStream.flush();
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to pass the `data` variable as the filename in `Content-Disposition`? Also, its closing quote is missing.

Comment: Above code is working fine for all other browsers..

Comment: Nevertheless, when you use non-standard features, like names of files which are actually image data and unclosed quotes, it means every browser is free to interpret it as it will. Thus, it will not work in all of them.

Comment: Agree what you are telling and made changes accordingly but it gives same problem.

Comment: OK, then. Can you give us the exact place where it throws that exception in your code? (If there's a stack trace, there's usually an indication for that there).

Comment: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:358)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:434)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:98)
        at com.cj.trim.trimFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

Instead of `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment,fileName=\"" + data);`

I have used `response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;fileName=\"" + data);`

and it works fine for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found some syntax errors in the code.

- Firstly, if possible use proper name for saving an image. Here I have taken a string `filename` and assigned the value `test.jpg` (You can change this as per your requirement).
- In the setHeader line, I found two syntax errors. There was an extra `/` and `"`

> ```
> String filename = "test.jpg";
> byte[] data = getImageData(path,imageName);
>
> response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
> response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
> response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
> response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;fileName=" + filename); 
> response.setContentLength(data.length);
> response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
>
> responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
> responseOutputStream.write(data, 0, data == null ? 0: data.length);
> responseOutputStream.flush();
> ```

Comment: It is working fine with all other IE version and mozila. only issue occurs on google chrome.

Comment: Try closing the Ouput Stream
`responseOutputStream.close();`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the `com.cj.trim.trimFilter` applied to your output. That filter should not be applied to anything whose output is not HTML. Here is [some documentation](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/trimflt.htm).